# Switch case in simple TicTacToe game

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I am writing simple tictactoe game. Everything went right until I got to changing turns. I created switch-case to change between X and O turn. Unfortunately when I click first cell it draws X but then it draws Os on each next one.

This is main class:

```
public class TicTacToe_10 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame ticTacToe = new Game_frame();
    ticTacToe.setTitle("TicTacToe Game");
    ticTacToe.setSize(600, 600);
    ticTacToe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ticTacToe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ticTacToe.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is my Cell class with Click class which contains switch-case:

```
public class Cell extends JPanel{

//dial of cell


protected static String dial="";
  String cturn=getTurn();


public Cell(){
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,1));
    addMouseListener(new Click());
}

//get and set dials

public static String getDial(){
    return dial;
}

public void setDial(String d){
    dial=d;
    repaint();
}

//defining shapes
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
   super.paintComponent(g);

   if (dial.equals("X")){
       g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth()-10, getHeight()-10);
       g.drawLine(getWidth()-10, 10, 10, getHeight()-10);
   }

   if(dial.equals("O")){
       g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth()-20, getHeight()-20);
   }

}


private class Click extends MouseAdapter
   {
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
       {

           // if the cell is empty 
           if (dial.equals(""))
               setDial(cturn);


           else
           {
               switch (cturn) {
                   case "X":
                       cturn="O";
                       setDial(cturn);
                       break;
                   case "O":
                       cturn="X";
                       setDial(cturn);
                       break;
               }


           }
       }
   } 

}
```

There is also game_frame class which just holds the cells:

```
public class Game_frame extends JFrame{

    private static String turn="X";

    //cell grid
    private  Cell[][] cells = new Cell[3][3];


    public Game_frame(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridLayout(3,3,0,0));
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                panel.add(cells[i][j] = new Cell());

        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder (Color.red,1));

        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static String getTurn(){
        return turn;
    } 
}
```

Comment: you should use a instance variable for `turn`.try to resize your frame .all set will get letter x or y

Comment: or minimize and maximize .all cell letter will same

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you did something wrong?
But I dont know really because i tried to test your code, and that didn't work as a method seems to be missing :/
I think it should be like this:

```
switch (dial) {
    case "X":
        cturn="O";
        setDial(cturn);
        break;
    case "O":
        cturn="X";
        setDial(cturn);
        break;
}
```

Comment: @FastSnail actually yes, because i was just really slow at typing and went to the toilet while typing and so I haven't seen his answer yet

Comment: @Cal Congrats :D I hope you will be able to work on bigger projects soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if i misunderstood the code,
i feel like it should be dial in switch.

```
 else
       {
           switch (dial) {
               case "X":
                   cturn="O";
                   setDial(cturn);
                   break;
               case "O":
                   cturn="X";
                   setDial(cturn);
                   break;
           }


       }
```